# Cannot open PDF in PDFViewer by GrepheneOS

Tags: android, git-submodules

I'm trying to built `https://github.com/GrapheneOS/PdfViewer`. I have downloaded the submodule as well but I cannot open the PDF. The logs from logcat are below. I'm using Windows OS

```
2022-11-02 00:12:37.712 21225-21279 PdfViewer D  path /viewer.html
2022-11-02 00:12:37.748 21225-21225 chromium  I  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'ambient-light-sensor'.", source:  (0)
2022-11-02 00:12:37.748 21225-21225 chromium  I  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'battery'.", source:  (0)
2022-11-02 00:12:37.748 21225-21225 chromium  I  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'hid'.", source:  (0)
2022-11-02 00:12:37.748 21225-21225 chromium  I  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)
2022-11-02 00:12:37.748 21225-21225 chromium  I  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'payment'.", source:  (0)
2022-11-02 00:12:37.748 21225-21225 chromium  I  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'picture-in-picture'.", source:  (0)
2022-11-02 00:12:37.748 21225-21225 chromium  I  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'serial'.", source:  (0)
2022-11-02 00:12:37.749 21225-21225 chromium  I  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'speaker-selection'.", source:  (0)
2022-11-02 00:12:37.749 21225-21225 chromium  I  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'usb'.", source:  (0)
2022-11-02 00:12:37.749 21225-21225 chromium  I  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'xr-spatial-tracking'.", source:  (0)
2022-11-02 00:12:37.752 21225-21279 PdfViewer D  path /pdfjs-dist/webpack.js
2022-11-02 00:12:37.752 21225-21271 PdfViewer D  path /viewer.css
2022-11-02 00:12:37.753 21225-21271 PdfViewer D  path /pdf.js
2022-11-02 00:12:37.760 21225-21271 PdfViewer D  path /viewer.js
2022-11-02 00:12:37.764 21225-21225 chromium  I  [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'", source: https://localhost/pdf.js (1)
2022-11-02 00:12:37.770 21225-21225 chromium  I  [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: pdfjsLib is not defined", source: https://localhost/viewer.js (3)
2022-11-02 00:12:37.772 21225-21279 PdfViewer D  path /favicon.ico
2022-11-02 00:12:37.773 21225-21225 chromium  I  [INFO:CONSOLE(203)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: pdfjsLib is not defined", source: https://localhost/viewer.js (203)
```